# find number in string with regex + xslt

Tags: regex, xslt, numbers, reddit

I'm trying to fetch the amount of comments out of the description of the following XML code:

```
    <item>
        <title>War Stats</title>
        <link>http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/comments/r3p6r/war_stats/</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/comments/r3p6r/war_stats/</guid>
        <pubDate>Mon, 19 Mar 2012 10:30:01 -0700</pubDate>
        <description>submitted by &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/focusing"&gt; focusing &lt;/a&gt; to &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/"&gt; politics&lt;/a&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;a href="http://i.imgur.com/8HpWg.jpg"&gt;[link]&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/comments/r3p6r/war_stats/"&gt;[634 comments]&lt;/a&gt;</description>
    </item>
```

as you can see I want to fetch the number 634 out of it and put it into a 'score' attribute of a new xml file

```
<xsl:attribute name="score">
    <xsl:analyze-string select='description' regex='\d'>
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <number><xsl:value-of select='.' /></number>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>

</xsl:attribute>
```

but I think I'm doing it wrong..

this is the entire code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>


<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="/rss/channel/item">
<item>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">reddit</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:variable name="redditTitle" content="title" />
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(title) &gt; 50">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(title, 1, 75), '...')" />    
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(title) &lt; 50">
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="url">
        <xsl:value-of select="link" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="image">http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8226356/Unief/DatabasesWebtechnologie/Praktijk/Project/Reddit_logo.thumbnail.png</xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="score">
        <xsl:analyze-string select='description' regex='[0-9]+'>
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>

    </xsl:attribute>
</item>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone explain me how to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression `\d` matches a single digit character, I think you want `\d+` or `[0-9]+` to match a sequence of digits.
And `xsl:attribute` outputs an attribute node, I don't see why inside of that you would then want to create an element node with `<number>...</number>` as attributes can't contain elements.
So make sure you use `xsl:attribute` inside of an result element or of `xsl:element` and then for the attribute value simply use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, then your code should work. If you still have problems then explain in more detail as to what output you want.

Comment: I'm trying to parse the reddit top articles into items with our new xml layout.

Comment: Throw out the `<number>`, that does not make any sense when computing an attribute value (of `score`) as you seem to want to do.

Comment: Still doesnt work, though I have no clue what the regex code actually does :S